# I have been running a Keras program for 1 month but now get the error: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'placeholder'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, jupyter

I have been running a Keras program for 1 month but now get the following error:

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'placeholder'

I use Anaconda3 with Tensorflow and Jupyter to run this code:

```
#keras222.py 
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Activation, Dense
```

Comment: Please, its not possible to say anything without more information, what you have given is not nearly enough to debug your problem.

Comment: This page should help: [mcve]

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I've unlocked the secret code! (Typing `[mcve]` creates the link you see above.)